# How to identify three palm lines in hand programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing

I am working on an android application in which I want to read palm lines when user clicks photo of his hand.

[image][image]

I have tried to google it but could not get desired results. I have also integrated the openCV library in my project but not sure how can I use it to detect those lines.
Is there any algorithm or library through which I can achieve it.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is similar with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no specific library to achieve that but you can use opencv to achieve it. Either you can train your own classifier to detect the plan lines or you can use edge detection to get all the edges and later use some mathematical logic to detect plan lines