# Why HoughLines find only 1 lines

Tags: python, opencv

I'm looking at an example from an official site Opencv: 
`https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html`
I attach the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines3.jpg',img)
```

Why does the program find only one line for an image even though the example found many lines?
I'm testing on the image attached below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV5my.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goQqh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You only draw one line make a loop for iterate all lines

```
for one_line in lines:
    for rho,theta in one_line:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
```

Comment: I did as you suggested but nothing changed. If i print(len(lines)), i receive 1

Comment: Then it can find only one line you should lower your threshold like that             lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,100)

Comment: as I understand HoughLines does not give an exact result?

Comment: You should modify your parameters for your situation check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv