# How to get only water level contour with OpenCV python on raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, picamera

[image]I am using raspberry pi4 (8GB) with pi camera to detect water level . I have defined a line from 0,375 to 800,375 . If top most point of water level contour goes above this line then I want to call a function. Here is my code and attached image of setup. How do I get water level contour only. Does it require canny edge detection over contours to get clear water level ? first I am getting largest contour and then defining its top most point.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time 
from datetime import datetime
    
    #color=(255,0,0)
    color=(0,255,0)
    thickness=2
    kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8) # added 01/07/2021
    picflag = 0 # set value to 1 once picture is taken
    
    # function to take still picture when water level goes beyond threshold
    
    def takepicture(frame):
      currentTime = datetime.now()
      picTime = currentTime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H%M%S") # Create file name for our picture
      text = currentTime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S") 
      font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX # font
      org = (05, 20) # org
      fontScale = 0.5 # fontScale
      color = (0, 0, 255) # Red color in BGR
      thickness = 1 # Line thickness of 2 px
      picName = picTime + '.png'
      image = cv2.putText(frame, text, org, font, fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA, False)
      cv2.imwrite(picName , image)
      picflag = 1
      return 
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while(True):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()  # ret = 1 if the video is captured; frame is the image
            
        # Our operations on the frame come here    
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0)
        gray= cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)   #to remove salt and paper noise 
    
        #ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,10,20,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,127,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
        thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel) # get outer boundaries only added 01/07/2021
        thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 5) # strengthen weak pixels added 01/07/2021
        img1, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)   
        #img1,contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) #added 01/07/2021
        cv2.line(frame, pt1=(0,375), pt2=(800,375), color=(0,0,255), thickness=2) # added 01/07/2021
        if len(contours) != 0:
                c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea) # find the largest contour
                #x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)          # get bounding box of largest contour
                img2=cv2.drawContours(frame, c, -1, color, thickness) # draw largest contour
                #img2=cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, color, thickness) # draw all contours
                #img3 = cv2.rectangle(img2,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)  # draw red bounding box in img
                #center = (x, y)
            #print(center) 
                left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
                right = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
                top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
                bottom = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
                # Draw dots onto frame
                cv2.drawContours(frame, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), 2)
                cv2.circle(frame, left, 8, (0, 50, 255), -1)
                cv2.circle(frame, right, 8, (0, 255, 255), -1)
                cv2.circle(frame, top, 8, (255, 50, 0), -1)
                cv2.circle(frame, bottom, 8, (255, 255, 0), -1)
                
                #print('left: {}'.format(left))
                #print('right: {}'.format(right))
                #print(format(top))
                top_countour_point = top[1]
                print(top_countour_point)
                #print('bottom: {}'.format(bottom))
                #if ((top_countour_point <= 375) and (picflag == 0)):   #checking if contour top point is above line
            #takepicture(frame)
                    #continue
                #if ((top_countour_point > 375) and (picflag == 0)) : 
                    #picflag = 0
                    #continue
        # Display the resulting image
        # cv2.line(frame, pt1=(0,375), pt2=(800,375), color=(0,0,255), thickness=2) # added 01/07/2021
        #cv2.imshow('Contour',img3)
        #cv2.imshow('thresh' ,thresh)
        cv2.imshow('Contour',frame)
       
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # press q to quit
           break
    
    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: you should add pictures to illustrate your problem. further, your code does very little. do not expect people on this site to solve your assignment for you.

Comment: In my own DIY project, I'd just use a water level sensor... much easier and more accurate than ANY AI solution.

Comment: it would make the problem a lot easier if you would invest some time to improve the physical condition of the image. For example if you would install some LED above or below the glass (you need to experiment) it would for sure improve the contrast of your region of interest with the surrounding area making it easier to write your algorithm

Answer (score 1):

### Caveats

As it was pointed out in the comments, there is very little to work with based on your post. In general, I agree with s0mbre that you'd be better of with a water level sensor, and with kavko, that if you do want to use a camera, you need to better control your environment, with lighting, camera angles, background, etc.

However, that is not to say that it is not possible with your current setup, assuming, that it is a static setup except for the water level. As such, there are some assumptions that we can make.

Here are the steps that I took to get an approximate approach:

### Gather image data

You have only provided one image with lines already on it, so that's not a lot to go on. What I did is that I removed the line that you added:

[image: Original image without the line]

Fortunately there wasn't too much of a line left afterwards.

### Image processing:

I have loaded the image (this would come from the code you have posted).

Using the assumptions above, I have decided to focus on a narrow slice of the image. I selected only the middle 60 pixels (1)

```
slc = frame[:, 300:360]
```

Next, I have converted it to greyscale (2)

```
gray_slc = cv2.cvtColor(slc, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

I have used Canny edge detection (see [docs here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html)) to find the edges in the image (3)

```
edges = cv2.Canny(gray_slc, 50, 90)
```

After that, I have applied a Hough Transform, to find all the edges (related [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560545/4441404)) (4)

```
rho = 1
theta = np.pi / 180
threshold = 15
min_line_length = 50
max_line_gap = 20

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), min_line_length, max_line_gap)
```

Given that I can assume that all of the top lines are the edge of the container, I averaged the y coordinates of the lines, and picked the lower most one as the water level:

```
y_avgs = [(line[0, 1] + line[0, 3]) / 2 for line in lines]

water_level = max(y_avgs)
```

Having this, I just checked, if it is over the threshold you have selected:

```
trigger_threshold = 375
    
if water_level > trigger_threshold:
    print("Water level is under the selected line")
```

[image: Results of the operations]

Now, keep in mind, I only had the one image to go on. Considering lighting conditions, yours results may vary.