# How to match 2D floorplans using python

Tags: python, opencv, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to match a 2D plan from a PDF and a vertical cut from a 3D software. After processing the 3D software render (A), I could get to this result (
[2D OpenCV processed image for lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP1mR.png)) using OpenCV line detection([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv)).

From where I can extract lines start and and positions.

And then I have lines that came from a PDF file. (B)
[2D Floorplan from PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfdPw.png)

Is there anyway I can find the corresponding region and scale from both datasets (A and B)?

The PDF can come with borders, tables and other lines that are not the actual 2D plan.
Thanks in advance.