# How do I find the center of multiple boxes in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm writing a python script that takes in a video input and should find the center of a tick tack toe board. As of right now I was able to find the contours of the board, but I don't know how to move forward in regards to finding the center of each little box.

Here's the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
while 1:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    c = 0
    for i in contours:
           area = cv2.contourArea(i)
           if area > 200:
                cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, c, (0, 255, 0), 3)
           c+=1
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break
```

and here's the frames that I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Concept

1. Use a basic algorithm to find the contours in the image. In this case, only 2 contours will be detected; the entire tic-tac-toe grid, and the center box of the tic-tac-toe grid.
2. Get the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the 2 contours, and sort them so that we know where to access the top-left point, top-right point, etc. of each of the 2 sets of points:

[image]

3. With the information we can calculate the center of each box. For each of the 4 corner boxes, simply find the center of the tip of the 2 lines that make up the boxes. For the rest of the boxes, simply find the center of the 4 points that make up the boxes:

[image]

#### The Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 0)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 100)
    kernel = np.ones((2, 2))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=8)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=2)

def convex_hull(cnt):
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, peri * 0.02, True)
    return cv2.convexHull(approx).squeeze()

def centers(inner, outer):
    c = inner[..., 0].argsort()
    top_lef2, top_rit2 = sorted(inner[c][:2], key=list)
    bot_lef2, bot_rit2 = sorted(inner[c][-2:], key=list)
    c1 = outer[..., 0].argsort()
    c2 = outer[..., 1].argsort()
    top_lef, top_rit = sorted(outer[c1][:2], key=list)
    bot_lef, bot_rit = sorted(outer[c1][-2:], key=list)
    lef_top, lef_bot = sorted(outer[c2][:2], key=list)
    rit_top, rit_bot = sorted(outer[c2][-2:], key=list)
    yield inner.mean(0)
    yield np.mean([top_lef, top_rit, top_lef2, top_rit2], 0)
    yield np.mean([bot_lef, bot_rit, bot_lef2, bot_rit2], 0)
    yield np.mean([lef_top, lef_bot, top_lef2, bot_lef2], 0)
    yield np.mean([rit_top, rit_bot, top_rit2, bot_rit2], 0)
    yield np.mean([top_lef, lef_top], 0)
    yield np.mean([bot_lef, lef_bot], 0)
    yield np.mean([top_rit, rit_top], 0)
    yield np.mean([bot_rit, rit_bot], 0)
    
img = cv2.imread(r"D:/OpenCV Projects/TicTacToe centers/tictactoe.png")
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
inner, outer = sorted(map(convex_hull, contours), key=len)

for x, y in centers(inner, outer):
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### The Output

[image]

#### The Explanation

1. Import the necessary libraries:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
```

2. Define a function, `process()`, that takes in an image array and returns a binary image *(that is the processed version of the image)* that will allow proper contour detection on the image later on:

```
def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 5), 0)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 100)
    kernel = np.ones((2, 2))
    img_dilate = cv2.dilate(img_canny, kernel, iterations=8)
    return cv2.erode(img_dilate, kernel, iterations=2)
```

3. Define a function, `convex_hull()`, that takes in a contour array and returns an array that is the convex hull of the approximated version of the contour:

```
def convex_hull(cnt):
    peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, peri * 0.02, True)
    return cv2.convexHull(approx).squeeze()
```

4. Define a function, `centers()`, that takes in two arrays; the convex hull of the inner box of the tic-tac-toe grid, and the convex hull of the entire tic-tac-toe grid. In the function, do the necessary sorting so that each individual point is in a variable with the variable name corresponding to the position of the point; this will allow for easy calculation of each center point:

```
def centers(inner, outer):
    c = inner[..., 0].argsort()
    top_lef2, top_rit2 = sorted(inner[c1][:2], key=list)
    bot_lef2, bot_rit2 = sorted(inner[c1][-2:], key=list)
    c1 = outer[..., 0].argsort()
    c2 = outer[..., 1].argsort()
    top_lef, top_rit = sorted(outer[c1][:2], key=list)
    bot_lef, bot_rit = sorted(outer[c1][-2:], key=list)
    lef_top, lef_bot = sorted(outer[c2][:2], key=list)
    rit_top, rit_bot = sorted(outer[c2][-2:], key=list)
```

5. Still within the `center()` function, yield the center of the boxes. The [`np.mean()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) method, when using `0` as the `axis` keyword argument, will return the center of the coordinates that are in the array of coordinates passed into the method:

```
    yield inner.mean(0)
    yield np.mean([top_lef, top_rit, top_lef2, top_rit2], 0)
    yield np.mean([bot_lef, bot_rit, bot_lef2, bot_rit2], 0)
    yield np.mean([lef_top, lef_bot, top_lef2, bot_lef2], 0)
    yield np.mean([rit_top, rit_bot, top_rit2, bot_rit2], 0)
    yield np.mean([top_lef, lef_top], 0)
    yield np.mean([bot_lef, lef_bot], 0)
    yield np.mean([top_rit, rit_top], 0)
    yield np.mean([bot_rit, rit_bot], 0)
```

6. Read in the image, find its contours *(also using the `process()` function to process the image first)*, find the convex hulls of the contours, and draw on the center of the boxes with the `centers()` function:

```
img = cv2.imread(r"D:/OpenCV Projects/TicTacToe centers/tictactoe.png")
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(process(img), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
inner, outer = sorted(map(convex_hull, contours), key=len)

for x, y in centers(inner, outer):
    cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
```

7. Finally, show the resulting image:

```
cv2.imshow("result", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: @kreaon My pleasure :) Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the right approach, since the tick-tack-toe board lines are connected, we will most likely always end up with a single large contour. To make things simple for your purpose, what you could try is detecting lines in the image.

You can try `cv2.HoughLinesP` or `cv2.createLineSegmentDetector` to identify lines. I am sure you can go ahead after detecting lines.

Also, you can go look into [How to detect lines in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv), different use case which can be extended for your purpose as well.