# Detect thick black lines in image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, houghlinesp

I have the following image of a lego board with some bricks on it

[image: sample image]

Now I am trying to detect the thick black lines (connecting the white squares) with OpenCV. I have already experimented a lot with HoughLinesP, converted the image to gray or b/w before, applied blur, ...
Nonthing led to usable results.

```
# Read image
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Resize Image
img =  cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25) 

# Initialize output
out = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Median blurring to get rid of the noise; invert image
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)

# Adaptive Treshold
bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,15,8)

# HoughLinesP
linesP = cv2.HoughLinesP(bw, 500, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 10)

# Draw Lines
if linesP is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
        l = linesP[i][0]
        cv2.line(out, (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0,0,255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

The adaptive treshold lets you see edges quite well, but with HoughLinesP you don't get anything usable out of it

[image: adaptive reshold]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

Thanks, both @fmw42 and @jeru-luke for your great solutions to this problem! I liked isolating / masking the green board, so I combined both:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")

scale_percent = 50 # percent of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# resize image
img = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
a_component = lab[:,:,1]

# binary threshold the a-channel
th = cv2.threshold(a_component,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# numpy black
black = np.zeros((img.shape[0],img.shape[1]),np.uint8)

# function to obtain the largest contour in given image after filling it
def get_region(image):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    mask = cv2.drawContours(black,[c],0,255, -1)
    return mask

mask = get_region(th)

# turning the region outside the green block white
green_block = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
green_block[black==0]=(255,255,255)

# median blur
median = cv2.medianBlur(green_block, 5)

# threshold on black
lower = (0,0,0)
upper = (15,15,15)
thresh = cv2.inRange(median, lower, upper)

# apply morphology open and close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (29,29))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# filter contours on area
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result = green_block.copy()
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000:
            cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
  

# view result
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv ?

Comment: AdaptiveThresholding shouldnt give you edges but areas, so the thresholding fails here. Try fixed color thresholding of near-black instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here I am presenting a repeated segmentation approach using color.
This answer is based on the usage of [LAB color space](https://www.xrite.com/blog/lab-color-space)

---

### 1. Isolating the green lego block

```
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
a_component = lab[:,:,1]

# binary threshold the a-channel
th = cv2.threshold(a_component,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

`th`
[image]

```
# function to obtain the largest contour in given image after filling it
def get_region(image):
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
    black = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]), np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.drawContours(black,[c],0,255, -1)
    return mask

mask = get_region(th)
```

`mask`
[image]

```
# turning the region outside the green block white
green_block = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
green_block[black==0]=(255,255,255)
```

`green_block`
[image]

---

### 2. Segmenting the road

- To get an approximate region of the road, I subtracted the `mask` and `th`.

`cv2.subtract()` performs arithmetic subtraction, where `cv2` will take care of negative values.

```
road = cv2.subtract(mask,th)
# `road` contains some unwanted spots/contours which are removed using the function "get_region"
only_road = get_region(road)
```

`only_road`
[image]

Masking only the road segment with the original image gives

```
road_colored = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = only_road)
road_colored[only_road==0]=(255,255,255)
```

`road_colored`
[image]

From the above image only the black regions (road) are present, which is easy to segment:

```
# converting to grayscale and applying threshold
th2 = cv2.threshold(road_colored[:,:,1],127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# using portion of the code from fmw42's answer, to get contours above certain area
contours = cv2.findContours(th2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result = img.copy()
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 4)
```

`result`
[image]

***Note:***
To clean up the end result, you can apply morphological operations on `th2` before drawing contours.

Comment: Nice approach. I did not threshold on green in my answer because I did not think he wanted the white squares.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the image
- Apply median blur
- Threshold on black color using cv2.inRange()
- Apply morphology to clean it up
- Get contours and filter on area
- Draw contours on input
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('black_lines.jpg')

# median blur
median = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)

# threshold on black
lower = (0,0,0)
upper = (15,15,15)
thresh = cv2.inRange(median, lower, upper)

# apply morphology open and close
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (29,29))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# filter contours on area
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
result = img.copy()
for c in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 1000:
            cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
  
# save result
cv2.imwrite("black_lines_threshold.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("black_lines_morphology.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("black_lines_result.jpg", result)

# view result
cv2.imshow("threshold", thresh)
cv2.imshow("morphology", morph)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Morphology image:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: great approach as always :)

Comment: Thanks. But mostly standard procedure. Just pick the right kind of thresholding for the problem at hand.

Comment: @fmw42 I borrowed your code snippet to find contours above fixed area :)

Comment: @JeruLuke haha it's like the same 10 people answering questions. I would have done pretty much the same exact thing too. That code style looks very familiar ;)