# Efficient Court Detection

Tags: python, opencv, houghlines

I'm trying to find an efficient, non-intensive way to detect tennis court lines. Essentially, a tennis broadcast has static camerawork and the model does not need to be robust like it would for other sports (basket-ball, hockey, etc.). Leveraging the long, static shot, I've been able to use Hough lines to get halfway there. What I'm thinking through now is a way to stitch together a polygon based on a sketch of it. From these red and green lines, I'd like to sketch the most likely polygon, in this case it should just fill out the exterior of the court. Does OpenCV have such a function?
[image]

```
# import the necessary packages
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2

# load the image
img = cv2.imread("assets/game-frames/clay-m-2012-71-870.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 100, apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 2, np.pi/180, 100, minLineLength=20, maxLineGap=10)

# Draw lines on the image
for line in lines:

    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]

    length = math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)
    
    if x1 == x2 or x1 < 10 or y1 < 100: 
        continue

    elif abs((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)) > 1.5 and abs((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)) < 3 and length > 200:
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    elif abs((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)) < 0.02 and ((x1 > 44 and x1 < 685) and (x2 < 685 and x2 > 44)) and ((y1 > 110 and y1 < 120) or (y1 > 400 and y1 < 420)):
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)

    else:
        continue 

cv2.imshow("Detected Lines (in red) - Standard Hough Line Transform", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I think I found your answer. Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv

Comment: Thanks! This is similar to what I have currently, except they pre-processed with a Gaussian blur, which is probably a good idea. I've actually just realized that I don't need to draw the rectangle. Knowing the regulation tennis court dimensions, we can use the horizontal lines to find the proper length of the lengthwise lines, and then from there we just project the court dimensions.

Comment: if the camera doesn't move, just enter the points manually (click on them, record the mouse position)

Comment: I'm trying to make it robust to small changes + different broadcasts, so it still needs to be automated. The problem to me is how to make it lightweight so it doesn't suck up resources - there are other things I'd like to do after locating the court.