image processing for ridges extraction from spectrogram
i would like to extract some ridges from an spectrogram:

I would like to extract, as cleanly as posible, the three separate red ridges that you can see in the previous espectrogram.
Working with matlab I have some results using the 'edge' (Edge detection function) function over a specific bandwidth:

But I would prefer not to filter because I don't know exactly where the signal is going to be and also because when you zoom you can see that there are "two" ridges instead of just one:

Any clues or directions to explore on how to solve this problem or improve this solution?
I'm not an image processing expert but I have some expertise on matlab and python signal processing.
Related code:
win=round(0.01*fs);%round(0.025890625*fs);
over=round(0.009*fs);%round(0.01875*fs);
[s,f,t,p] =spectrogram(song,hamming(win),over,fs,fs,'yaxis');
BW=edge(p(6000:22000,:),[],'vertical');
imagesc(BW); axis xy

All the best

If you want to detect ridges, don’t use an edge detector. Did you google for “ridge detector”? This is also called “line detector” in the literature. Here’s four of the better algorithms (I implemented: them there): https://diplib.org/diplib-docs/detection_lines.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv then filter out which lines you want

Also, I am not sure what is the magnitude scale you have in spectrogram (logarithmic - dB?). There is a chance that in different domain (energy/magnitude) it may be easier to extract the lines

plots aren't data. [mre] required.

thanks @CrisLuengo I'll check your implementations and literature.

thanks @dankal444 but I guess this solution is for straight lines, isn't? The magnitude is energy and I agree that it has better behaviour because of the higher range

thanks @ChristophRackwitz but I think I can't upload the audio because of my lack of privileges.. Some png will be good for you?
All the best
